# Delete only specific elements of a dynamically allocated array of structure objects

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, free

Below I am allocating an array of 5 structure objects using `new[]`, out of which only 3 i have used to put my data & the rest i want to delete. Below is the program. It produces the compilation error mentioned at the end.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Test
{
        int data;
        Test() { cout<<"struct created"<<endl; }
};
int main()
{
        Test *t1;
        t1 = new Test[5];
        int i,n;
        n=3;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                t1[i].data=(i+10);
        while(i<5)
        {
                delete t1[i];
                i++;
        }
}
```

The compilation error is

```
error: type ‘struct Test’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer
```

Comment: @bku_drytt It's not a good idea...

Comment: As per your code, you can delete entire array which is pointed by "t1". You cannot delete individual elements of array.  If you had used "Test *t1[5]; and then allocated memory for each of these 5 pointers then you could have deleted any element"

Comment: This is undefined behavior. Don't do it. You can explicitly call destructor for those objects. Free memory allocated with `new[]` only with `delete[]`

Comment: The simple answer is that you can't "delete" things from an array like that. If you want to be able to dynamically add *or* remove elements use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @teivaz Wouldn't that lead to executing the elements' destructors again when the array is deleted (or not delete the array and have a mem leak)?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider yes you are right but it can be used with combination of placement new to create an object in the already allocated memory. I am not encouraging anyone to use it, but it is possible.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes but i wanted to understand the actual use of delete instead of using destructor, because I wanted to learn the actual use of delete, so i tried using this way, I understand as & when object is going out of scope its better to delete entire object

Comment: The actual use of `delete` is to free object you allocate with `new`, and you use `delete[]` to free arrays of objects allocated with `new[]`. That's it, unless you have actually allocated an object with `new` don't try to free or destruct it with `delete`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, got a clear understanding on the delete, since new points to the first object allocated..... we cant delete the only the particular array object..... Well thanks to all for making it clearly understand

Answer (score 2):

An array, during its lifetime, contains exactly as many objects as it did when it was first created. You cannot add more nor "delete" them away. All of the contained objects will be destroyed when the array is destroyed.

If you want an array with variable number of objects, then you're looking for `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you can't delete an element from the array, is because you allocated a range of memory for this array. And you can't free a part of what you allocated. It's all or nothing. Same thing when you allocate an object, you can't free a part of it.

If you want to delete object from an array (without using a std::vector as user2079303 said), you can still use an array of pointers.
But you will have to manage yourself each element when the array have to be destroyed (which doesn't seem to be a good idea to do).